# display picture every 5 sec

Tags: android, image

I have to change pictures from my gallery after every 5 seconds. Can anyone tell me how to do that?
Here is a part of my code:

```
private final Integer[] mImage = { R.drawable.picture, R.drawable.picture_1 };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);


    final Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));



}`
```

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct is to suggest you investigate how to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) however I believe a better option is to use the [postDelayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method with a 5 second delay and a runnable that updated the image and posts the next delayed update (if the app is still active).

Comment: ok, thanks. But I still don't know how i can move these pictures in run()((((